# How to deploy WAR file to Tomcat using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I'm using Maven in my Java project and I want to deploy the WAR to my localhost Tomcat.

I have this lines in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.target>C:\Directory</tomcat.target>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <webappDirectory>${tomcat.target}</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The output logs are:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Directory\name.war to C:\Directory\name.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Directory\pom.xml to C:\Directory\name.pom
```

As you can see I want to config this line:

> **to** C:\Directory\name.war

How to point it to Tomcat's /webapps folder?

Comment: Did you try pointing it to Tomcat's /webapps folder?

Comment: @Sudhanshu that what I want to config, I updated my question.

Comment: You must be having CATALINA_HOME set, you can try to use that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/mkyongWebApp</path>
                </configuration>
```

check the link http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a different Tomcat manager URL

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://www.example.com:1234/mymanager</url>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

See the [usage page](http://mojohaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using netbeans add this to your pom

```
    <properties>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat70</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>
```

or else you can use these links http://winfig.com/?p=76 and http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-tomcat.html